# Headers disappear in integration test on REST service

Tags: spring, rest, grails, testing

I have an integration test in my Grails 3.2.2 application that is supposed to check that CORS support is operational. When I start the application and use something like Paw or Postman to do a request, the breakpoint I have set in CorsFilter shows that my headers are set properly. But when I do the same request from an integration test using RestBuilder with the following code:

```
void "Test request http OPTIONS"() {
    given: "JSON content request"

    when: "OPTIONS are requested"
    def rest = new RestBuilder()
    def optionsUrl = url(path)
    def resp = rest.options(optionsUrl) {
        header 'Origin', 'http://localhost:4200'
        header 'Access-Control-Request-Method', 'GET'
    }

    then: "they are returned"
    resp.status == HttpStatus.SC_OK
    !resp.json
}
```

The breakpoint in CorsFilter shows that both headers are null:

[image]

And the weird thing is that when I put a breakpoint in RestTemplate, right before the request is executed, the headers are there:

[image]

I don't get how those headers can disappear. Any idea?

Comment: It's worth either using a proxy (like Fiddler) or a Wireshark to capture the traffic that you send/receive to at least find out which side to blame.

Answer (score 2):

I was working on this problem problem recently, and while I don't know where RestBuilder is suppressing the Origin header, I did come up with a workaround for testing that grails' CORS support is operating as configured: using HTTPBuilder instead of RestBuilder to invoke the service.

After adding `org.codehaus.groovy.modules.http-builder:http-builder:0.7.1` as a testCompile dependency in `build.gradle`, and with `grails.cors.allowedOrigins` set to `http://localhost`, the following tests both worked as desired:

```
import geb.spock.GebSpec
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException
import groovyx.net.http.Method

@Integration
class ExampleSpec extends GebSpec {
    def 'verify that explicit, allowed origin works'() {
        when:
        def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://localhost:${serverPort}/todo/1")
        def result = http.request(Method.GET, "application/json") { req ->
            headers.'Origin' = "http://localhost"
        }

        then:
        result.id == 1
        result.name == "task 1.1"
    }

    def 'verify that explicit, disallowed origin is disallowed'() {
        when:
        def http = new HTTPBuilder("http://localhost:${serverPort}/todo/1")
        http.request(Method.GET, "application/json") { req ->
            headers.'Origin' = "http://foobar.com"
        }

        then:
        HttpResponseException e = thrown()
        e.statusCode == 403
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like HTTPBuilder doesn't support OPTIONS requests, which seems completely absurd.

Comment: Even though it doesn't solve the problem because of the missing OPTIONS, it is nevertheless a good attempt, so you're getting the bounty. Enjoy the ten-fold reputation increase. :)

Answer (score 0):

Had same problem. After some research I found out: http://hc.apache.org/, it supports sending 'Origin' and options requests.

```
 import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
 import grails.transaction.Rollback
 import groovy.util.logging.Slf4j
 import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient
 import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpOptions
 import org.apache.http.impl.client.MinimalHttpClient
 import org.apache.http.impl.conn.BasicHttpClientConnectionManager
 import spock.lang.Specification

 @Integration
 @Rollback
 @Slf4j
 class CorsIntegrationSpec  extends Specification {

     def 'call with origin'() {
         when:
         def response = call(["Origin":"test","Content-Type":"application/json"])
         then:
         response != null
         response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200
         response.containsHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin")
         response.containsHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials")
         response.containsHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers")
         response.containsHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods")
         response.containsHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age")
     }  

     private call (Map<String, String> headers) {
         HttpOptions httpOptions = new HttpOptions("http://localhost:${serverPort}/authz/token")
         headers.each { k,v ->
             httpOptions.setHeader(k,v)
         }
         BasicHttpClientConnectionManager manager = new BasicHttpClientConnectionManager()
         HttpClient client = new MinimalHttpClient(manager)
         return client.execute(httpOptions)
     }
 }
```